# Generating SHA512 HMAC not working from the command line

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to generate a SHA256 HMAC using the openssl command line, but the output isn't correct.  Comparing to the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Examples) I'm getting something different:

```
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "key" <<< "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"                                                                                                  
(stdin)= abb26bc1a42fb16503a4d5b44d5082ed8fe79229b3c057c6d770956777b83b15
```

A quick PHP example that generates the same result as the Wikipedia example:

```
print hash_hmac('sha256', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'key');
f7bc83f430538424b13298e6aa6fb143ef4d59a14946175997479dbc2d1a3cd8
```

I've tried a variety of options for the openssl command, but can't figure out I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware.  I'll post there in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The here string (`<<<`) adds a newline to the text, so you are actually calculating the HMAC of the string:

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n"
```

Using `echo -n` and piping into `openssl` works as you would expect:

```
$ echo -n "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "key"
f7bc83f430538424b13298e6aa6fb143ef4d59a14946175997479dbc2d1a3cd8
```

Comment: Bah! Thanks so much.